# MBA camera or iPhone camera for analysing tennis shots in slow motion?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro

I want to practise tennis shots and see how I am doing. I want to use the MBA camera in my laptop or iPhone for this. How can I do it? Some apps for this purpose?

*Please keep the focus on Apple products, photography-oriented answers [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49449/how-many-pictures-per-second-for-analysing-training-tennis-shots-in-slow-motion).*

Comment: I would definately recommend a sport-camera for this.

Answer (score 3):

The MBA build in cameras wont do high rate frames per second needed for your purpose.

They are a web camera type and the CCD/CMOS chip is not of a kind that can do that, regardless of the software.

iSight is a webcam, with video capture at 30 frames per second in 24-bit color.

On the iPhone there is a chance since it has an improved camera:

The iPhone 5s has a 120-frames-per-second slow-motion video mode and precision autofocus matrix metering.

Sport events would use 300 FPS on a professional level with high resolution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to measure how fast you're serving you might want to get [Tennis Camera](https://itunes.apple.com/app/tennis-camera/id796061345?ls=1&mt=8). The app measures your serve speed in real time and reconstructs the 3D trajectory of your shot. An iPhone 5 or newer is required.

*Disclaimer: I'm one of the devs behind the app.*

Answer (score 1):

Try ubersense app.  In my opinion you do not need the high speed video cameras to get 99% of the info you are after.  You can also use your iPhone from on top of the fence with a qm-1 from mytennistools.com